# How can I delete a certain message in a file in this case?

Tags: php

I am working on a simple message board. I can send messages to mission_3-3.txt properly at this point. However, i can't delete a certain message in a text file by putting a number in a text box. I tried showing messages if the number of array does't match with the number i put in a text box and not showing a message if the number matches, but It did't work correctly. Could you help me with this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>mission_3-3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="名前">
            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="コメント">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <form>
            <input type="number" name="delNo" placeholder="投稿番号">
            <input type="submit" name="delete">
        </form>
        <?php
            $filename = "mission_3-3.txt";
        
            if(!empty($_POST["submit"])) {
            
                $name =$_POST["name"];
                $content = $_POST["content"];
                $date = date("Y/m/d/H:i:d");
        
                if(file_exists($filename)) {
                    $num = count(file($filename)) + 1;
                } else {
                    $num = 1;
                }
             
                $integrate = $num . "<>" . $name . "<>" . $content . "<>" . $date . PHP_EOL;
            
                $fp = fopen($filename, "a");
                fwrite($fp, $integrate);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        
            if(!empty($_POST["delete"])) {
            
                $delete = $_POST["delNo"];
                $delLines = file("mission_3-3.txt");
                $fp = fopen("mission_3-3.txt", "a");
                for($i=0;$i<count($delLines);$i++) {
                    $delData = explode("<>", $delLines[$i]);
                    if($delData[0] != $delete) {
                        fwrite($fp, $delLines[$i]);
                    } else {
                        //write "deleted" in mission_3-3.txt
                        fwrite($fp, "消去しました。\n");
                    }
                } 
                fclose($fp);
            }
        
        
            //$files = file($filename);
            //foreach($files as $file) {
                //なんで代入する必要がある？
                //$lines = explode("<>", $file);
                //echo $file . PHP_EOL;
            //}
        ?>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Using `"a"` in the `fopen()` will append the data, if you want to replace the data use `"w"`.

Comment: @Sammitch Why `w+` instead of `w`? I notice that most code on SO uses the `+` modifier unnecessarily.

Comment: Sammitch - the difference between `w` and `w+` is that `w+` includes reading from the file too. As he read nothing from the file, it's not necessary. It doesn't break anything tho.

Comment: Maybe I should hold off on answering questions until the coffee has actually kicked in...

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is the following:

```
$numberToDelete = $_POST['delNo'];
$fileLines = file('mission_3-3.txt');

foreach ($fileLines as $key => $line) {
    $lineData = explode('<>', $line);

    if ($lineData[0] === $numberToDelete) {
        $fileLines[$key] = '消去しました。' . "\n";
        break;
    }
}

file_put_contents('mission_3-3.txt', $fileLines, LOCK_EX);
```

This is simpler than writing line by line again. At least less IO.

As suggested by @Mirabeau if this system is going to be used with high concurrency you can add the `LOCK_EX` flag to the `file_put_contents` so you can prevent two users writing to the same file in the same exact moment. But as far as I can see from the code, I doubt that there will be THAT many traffic that this can happen.
That flag, however, will not prevent anyone from overwriting the same file, even if they didn't see the last changes. If they hit the save button a millisecond later - they will overwrite everything with whatever they have loaded.

Otherwise as others mentioned above, you can use `w` flag on `fopen` instead, so you truncate the file before writing each line again to it.

Comment: It looks as though rather than just unsetting the line, OP replaces the line.  Not sure if that is just what they have tried or it's a requirement.  Also just a note - you can pass an array to `file_put_contents()` instead of having to do the `implode()`.

Comment: I added the way above inside if(!empty($_POST["delete"])) {}, but it did not delete an exact message in 'mission_3-3.txt'. Does this part ($fileLines[$key] = '消去しました。' . "\n";) work as  deleting a message under the condition?

Comment: It should replace the line with that string, as you initially wanted in the question. It does not delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

*(sorry i can't add a comment, <50 reputation)*

@vuryss answer is the right way, i only had just one thing:

```
file_put_contents('mission_3-3.txt', implode('', $fileLines), LOCK_EX);
```

LOCK_EX avoid the worry of simultaneous writing

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments, the `a` mode *appends* to the file, where `w` will truncate the file and open it for writing.

However, the trouble with writing to a file in-place is that if something goes wrong in the middle you've got a half-written file and nothing to go back to. The safer version would be something like:

```php
$cur = 'mission_3-3.txt';
$tmp = tempnam('./', 'foo');

$f_tmp = fopen($tmp, 'w');

for( ... ) {
  // your existing code here
}

fclose($f_tmp);
unlink($cur);
rename($tmp, $cur);
```

Comment: If the data was that important then I would recommend using a database for reliability as opposed to flat files.

Comment: @NigelRen very yes.

Comment: When you look at the code, do you really think this is implemented in a fault-tolerant system, where outages will be handled the correct way?  :)
He's just learning to code. He will learn with time and when the challenges become greater.

Comment: @vuryss the hope is that we say "look out for that pit, we fell in it once!" and then they don't have to learn about it the hard way. `:P`